# The function all() in R

Tags: r

Why is it that:

```
> 'c' %in% c('c', 'b')
[1] TRUE
```

But

```
> all('c' %in% c('c', 'b'))
[1] TRUE
```

Shouldn't this be false?

According to the documentation:

> Are All Values True?
>
> Description
>
> Given a set of logical vectors, are all of the values true?

I gave it a set of logical vectors, and NOT ALL of the values are true.r

Comment: Because the way you wrote it, `'c' %in% c('c', 'b')` all the values in the result *are* true.  Try flipping it around to `c('c', 'b') %in% 'c'`

Comment: Why can't it be read, "I'm testing to see if 'c' is in the vector holding 'c' and 'b'"??

Comment: That's the way it is read.  The function reads "is x in table?", so if you write `'c' %in% c('c', 'b')` you are asking "is `'c'` in `c('c', 'b')`?", and that is true

Comment: It is and the answer is yes, 'c' is in the vector. And when you ask `all('c' %in% c('c', 'b'))`, you ask `all(TRUE)`, which is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CASE 1:**

```
> 1:4 %in% 1:10
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

In this case logical vector is returned. Since each element of 1:4 is present      in 1:10 we are getting TRUE for all elements.

**CASE 2:**

```
 > 1:11 %in% 1:10
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[11] FALSE
```

We are getting TRUE for all except 11 as 11 is not in 1:10

**CASE 3:**

```
all(1:4 %in% 1:10)
[1] TRUE
```

If we use all() it will return either TRUE or FALSE.It will tell whether all elements of 1:4 are present in 1:10 or not.

**CASE 4:**

```
> all(1:11 %in% 1:10)
[1] FALSE
```

Since 11 is not in 1:10 thats why we are getting FALSE.

Now you can solve your problem very easily. all() return TRUE if all conditions are TRUE otherwise return FALSE.